# how to display a server

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

Hi I want to display with a console.log What discord server something happend in so it would look like 
`2MP said a banned word in (servername)`

I've got this so for

```
// deletes banned messages
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.id === client.user.id) return;
  if (config.FILTER_LIST.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
    message.delete().catch(() => {})
    embed.setTitle(`Hello`);
    embed.setDescription(`${message.author} You'r message was removed \n **Reason: You said a banned word**`);
    embed.setColor('#FF0000');
    message.author.send(embed).catch(() => {})
    console.log(`${message.author.username} just said a word they shoulnt of`);
  }
})
```

Comment: What error are you receiving/what is not working?

Comment: I'm not receiving a error I want to know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// deletes banned messages
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.id === client.user.id) return;
  if (config.FILTER_LIST.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
    message.delete().catch(() => {})
    embed.setTitle(`Hello`);
    embed.setDescription(`${message.author} You'r message was removed \n **Reason: You said a banned word**`);
    embed.setColor('#FF0000');
    message.author.send(embed).catch(() => {})
    console.log(`${message.author.username} just said a word they shoulnt of ${message.guild.name}`);
  }
})
```

i think message.guild.name is what u want